# Is it a way to know when upload file is done? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a web application where client can upload files using the FIleUpload ASP.NET control. Is it a way for me to know that upload is finished so I can for example kill the session?

Comment: upload finish as soon as you read the file, show some code pls

Comment: Agreed, but imagine that many users may be online trying to upload many different files and I need to know if an upload is in progress server side.

Comment: keep thread-safe count of uploaders, increment/decrement when upload starts finish, if count = 0 no uploading in progress...

Comment: ASP.NET handles such concurrencies internally unless and until you are not implementing multi-threading by yourself (i think but not very sure)

Comment: @samar, ASP.NET handles thread safety of all objects like HttpContext and etc. but never will do synchronization for your logic

Comment: @ArsenMkrt. Correct. But how do I know upload is finished? Back to my initial question

Comment: @MelkorS.K as I said, as soon as you complete reading the stream, the upload finished, show some code, how are you reading the file? for example after FileUploadControl.SaveAs(...); method file is read, and upload is finished(if no exception of course)

Comment: Solved it with FileSystemWatcher. This helped a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822175/filesystem-watcher-and-large-files