# Out-of-mem-Exception in c# GUI when using FileSystemWatcher - multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, out-of-memory, filesystemwatcher

I build a windows-forms-app where I (try to) do extensive calculations on images whenever they are created in a specific directory which I watch using the FileSystemWatcher.

```
private void OnNewFileInDir(object source, FileSystemEventArgs evtArgs) 
{  
  //Load the actual image:
  imageFilepath = evtArgs.FullPath;  //imageFilepath is a private class string var
  Image currentImage = Image.FromFile(imageFilepath);

  //Display the image in the picture box:
  UpdatePictureBox(currentImage);     //Method to update the GUI with invoking for the UI thread

  //Extensive Calculation on the images
  Image currentResultImage = DoExtensiveWork(currentImage);

  // Put the current result in the picture box
  UpdatePictureBox(currentResultImage );

  //dispose the current/temporary image
  currentImage.Dispose();
}
```

The event is fired correctly when pasting a new file into the directory. But I get a "System.OutOfMemoryException" on the line

```
Image currentImage = Image.FromFile(imageFilepath);
```

When I put exactly this code (using the same filepath) in a button event (so not using the FileSystemWatcher) everything works fine. So I thought there is some issue regarding the thread since the extensive calculation is then called by the FileSystemWatcher-Thread not by the UI thread.

I tried things like:

```
//TRY 1: By executing a button click method containg the code
pb_Calculate_Click(this, new EventArgs());    //This does not work eigther --> seems to be a problem with "Who is calling the method"

//TRY 2: Open a new dedicated thread for doing the work of the HistoCAD calculations
Thread newThread_OnNewFile = new Thread(autoCalcAndDisplay);
newThread_OnNewFile.Start();


//TRY 3: Use a background worker as a more safe threading method(?)
using (BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker())
{
   bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
   if (bw.IsBusy == false)
   {
      bw.RunWorkerAsync();
   }
}
```

Unfortunalty none of them worked reliable. 1st not at all. 2nd works only from time to time and 3rd one as well.

Do some of you know whats going on there? What can I do to make it work correctly? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the comments:
I also tried to call GC.collect() on every event and tried to include using() and dispose() wherever I can. When I'm doing the process manually (with buttons) it works even when processing a lot of files one after another. But when done with the eventhandler I sometimes get the outOfMem-Exception even on the very first file I copy in the folder. File is always the same BMP with 32MB. This is the memory usage for processing one image:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I created a minimal example (GUI with one picture Box and one Checkbox in buttonstyle). It turns out that the same thing is happening. The OutOfMemException occured at the same line (Image...). Especially for large BMPs the exception occours nearly always:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimalExampleTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string imageFilepath;
        private string autoModePath = @"C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\bmpordner";

        //Define a filesystem watcher object
        private FileSystemWatcher watcher;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            /*** Creating as FileSystemEventArgs watcher in order to monitor a specific folder ***/
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            Console.WriteLine(watcher.Path);
            // set the path if already exists, otherwise we have to wait for it to be set
            if (autoModePath != null)
                watcher.Path = autoModePath;
            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times and renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            // Only watch for BMP files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.bmp";
            // Add event handler. Only on created, not for renamed, changed or something
            // Get into the list of the watcher. Watcher fires event and "OnNewFileCreatedInDir" will be called
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnNewFileInDir);


        }

        private void tb_AutoMode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //First of all test if the auto mode path is set and correctly exists currently:
            if (!Directory.Exists(autoModePath) || autoModePath == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check if Auto Mode path is correctly set and if path exists",
                    "Error: Auto Mode Path not found");
                return;
            }

            // Begin watching if the AutoModePath was at least set
            if (autoModePath != null)
            {
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = tb_AutoMode.Checked;  //Since we have a toogle butten, we can use the 'checked' state to enable or disable the automode
            }

        }


        private void OnNewFileInDir(object source, FileSystemEventArgs evtArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New file in detected: " + evtArgs.FullPath);

            //Force a garbage collection on every new event to free memory and also compact mem by removing fragmentation.
            GC.Collect();

            //Set the current filepath in the class with path of the file added to the folder:
            imageFilepath = evtArgs.FullPath;

            //Load the actual image:
            Image currentImage = Image.FromFile(imageFilepath);

            UpdatePictureBox(currentImage);

        }

        private void UpdatePictureBox(Image img)
        {
            if (pictureBox_Main.InvokeRequired)
            {
                MethodInvoker mi = delegate
                {
                    pictureBox_Main.Image = img;
                    pictureBox_Main.Refresh();
                };
                pictureBox_Main.Invoke(mi);
            }
            else {  //Otherwise (when the calculation is perfomed by the GUI-thread itself) no invoke necessary
                pictureBox_Main.Image = img;
                pictureBox_Main.Refresh();
            }
            img.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for further hints :)

Comment: `Image currentImage = Image.FromFile(imageFilepath);` has nothing to do with the UI thread. If it would you would've gotten a `System.InvalidOperationException` instead. I think your problem is rather related to your image not being entirely written before you read it.

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: The Image class is the singular .NET class that is highly unforgiving to forgetting to call Dispose().  It uses very little GC heap and *lots* of unmanaged memory.  Extra bad because your code appears to not give the GC much of a workout so you don't have it clean up for you.  Crystal ball says that your UpdatePictureBox() forgets to dispose the old PictureBox.Image.  If that doesn't help then use a memory profiler or get desperate enough to count OnNewFileInDir() calls and call GC.Collect() every, say, 100 times.

Comment: No clue from the code how a 32MB bmp image could possibly cause your program to need almost a gigabyte.  You are now liable to hit the restrictions of a 32-bit process, needing a single allocation of ~90 MB can fail when the program has been running for a while and the address space got fragmented.  Removing the jitter forcing so it can run as a 64-bit process is the very simple workaround for that.

Comment: @Hans: In the background (when 1GB is used) there is a quite sophisticated DLL which devides the image in tiles and calculates over 200 properties for each tile.

Comment: @Vincent: I had exaclty this exception in the beginning. Thats why I use my "UpdatePicturebox"-Method where I have to use a MethodInvoker to delegate the job.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know what the problem actually is. That said, `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown by `Image` for a variety of file corruption or format problems. It is possible your image file is an invalid format, or you are trying to read it before it's valid (i.e. while some other process is still writing to it). On the latter point, you can try using `FileStream` to open the file explicitly, and use exclusive access to the file, to make sure you can't open it if some other process still has it open.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the comment...I created such an example and will post it in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

The issue seems to be, that event is fired immediately but the file is not yet finally copied. That means we have to wait until the file is free.
A Thread.Sleep(100) at the start of the event does the job. As I now know what to google for, I found two links:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822175/filesystem-watcher-and-large-files) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can find:

> The OnCreated event is raised as soon as a file is created. If a file is being copied or transferred into a watched directory, the OnCreated event will be raised immediately, followed by one or more OnChanged events

So, what works best for my case, was to include a method to test if the file is still locked and than wait at the beginning of the event for an unlock of the file. No need for an additional thread or a BackgroundWorker. 
See the code:

```
private void OnNewFileInDir(object source, FileSystemEventArgs evtArgs)
{
   Console.WriteLine("New file detected: " + evtArgs.FullPath);

   //Wait for the file to be free
   FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(evtArgs.FullPath);
   while (IsFileLocked(fInfo))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("File not ready to use yet (copy process ongoing)");
       Thread.Sleep(5);  //Wait for 5ms
   }

   //Set the current filepath in the class with path of the file added to the folder:
   imageFilepath = evtArgs.FullPath;
   //Load the actual image:
   Image currentImage = Image.FromFile(imageFilepath);    
   UpdatePictureBox(currentImage);
}

private static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        //try to get a file lock
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
       //File isn't ready yet, so return true as it is still looked --> we need to keep on waiting
       return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null){ 
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
    // At the end, when stream is closed and disposed and no exception occured, return false --> File is not locked anymore
    return false;
}
```

Nevertheless: Thanks for your help...it got me on the right track;)

Comment: Congratulations. Nice to see you found it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

As MSDN says about [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised. Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.

Maybe your Image is loaded severals times.

To test it, you can add this line after `imageFilepath = evtArgs.FullPath;`

```
imageFilepath = evtArgs.FullPath;
Task.Run(()=>{MessageBox.Show(imageFilepath);});
```

This will inform you about the fact that the `Created` event is fired, and will not hold up your program.

**Edit**

Put your line of code that give the `OutOfMemory` in a Try Catch.
Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848132/out-of-memory-image-fromfile) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108607/out-of-memory-exception-on-system-drawing-image-fromfile) questions describes, you can get this error if your image is corrupt.

Comment: I added the line and it just shows the correct new filepath in the messagebox. The OutOfMemException still occurs after that

Comment: And you get the messagebox only once?

Comment: yes, only one msgbox! I have read the first post before and also tried it. But I think it is unlikly that it is because of the image format. Since it is working when done without FileSystemWatcher in an extra button for example. Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: BTW: I can open the image with any other program (windows pic view, paint, PS) and it works from time to time with the program as well. On my PC I have 8GB RAM and at least 4 GB available at the moment in Win10.    AND: I also tried with different (and small) BMPs. The smaller the BMP the faster I have to paste new BMPs in the folder to get the error (for a 500 kB BMP about 2-3 per second)

Comment: I would help you more but I'm afraid I can't help you further.