# Keeping console app from closing but still run codes

Tags: c#, console-application, stopwatch

I have a console app that does not terminate using a code

```
new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
```

**What I want to achieve:** I would want to run a `StopWatch` and if it meets a condition it will run certain file manipulating codes. And then finally after the block of code, resets the timer and wait for it to be `true` again to rerun.

**Problem:** However, upon debugging I cant get my code to go through my conditions even it has already passed the required condition.

My Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mutex_id = "41585f436f766572743243494d";
        using (System.Threading.Mutex mtx = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, mutex_id))
        {
            if(!mtx.WaitOne(0,false))
            {
                return;
            }
            processTimer = new Stopwatch();
            processTimer.Start();

            if (processTimer.Elapsed.Seconds > 10)
            {
                processTimer.Stop();
                fileQueue = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatchPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Format"]).ToList();
            }
            //process the fileQueue
            //..
            //..
            //processTimer.Reset(); -> Reset Timer to wait for another 10 sec and process again
            new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
        }
    }
```

I have used a `FileSystemWatcher` before but I failed to get the process correctly(Like Consecutive/Concurrent file creations and such). Tried `Threading` and `Timers` as my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266607/how-to-deal-with-rapid-consecutive-file-creation-in-a-folder-watched-by-a-filesy).

Now I'm trying to approach this issue from a new perspective. Hope some can enlighten me with this.

Comment: Why are you using a [`StopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than, say, a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "try again" in your code.

The code you've written does the following:

1. Create a mutex and lock it
2. If it already exists, close application
3. Start a stopwatch
4. Check if 10 seconds elapsed (which they didn't)
5. Create a new AutoResetEvent and **wait for ever for it**

You will need some loop that periodically checks if 10 seconds have passed and otherwise [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yea figured it out few hours before. Just made an infinite `while` loop and do things. Anyway thanks.